# why stmt.Close is slow?

Tags: go

We implemented an Clickhouse driver according to sql/driver with ConnPrepareContext interface which use stmt to do the real querying work.

For some queries, our driver cost must of the time during stmt.Close(). I can find the query execution time in Clickhouse system.query_log.
For 10 out of 4000 queries in production environment, I found they executed very fast in Clikchouse but cost too much in driver.
Take one query as example: it run 100ms in Clickhouse and resulted 0 rows, but the driver cost 10s on the Close() method.

This issue is not easy to reproduce. I want to ask you for help. If this is database/sql package issue, it should not only emerge in my driver, but also other drivers. Does anyone meet the same issue?

Can you give some suggestion on how to debug this.

Comment: It is almost impossible to say why some code may be slow without seeing it. I recommend using [pprof](https://go.dev/blog/pprof) and or [trace](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime/trace) to figure out where and why your code might be slow

Answer (score 0):

I find some hints.

In one `sql.DB.QueryContext()` call, our driver will
step 1: call `sql.DB.PrepareContext()` to prepare `sql.Stmt`, and
step 2: call `sql.Stmt.QueryContext()`, and
step 3: run `sql.Stmt.finalClose()` due to `Rows.Close()`

Both in step 1 and step 2, sql.Stmt will apply one `sql.driverConn`, and append it into `sql.Stmt.css`.
In step 3, `sql.Stmt` will be removed in each `sql.driverConn` in `sql.Stmt.css`, which will acquire `sql.driverConn` lock. This will cause contention.

In our case, we don't care so much about security. We will implement QueryerContext interface in Golang sql/driver avoid unnecessary PrepareContext.

refer http://go-database-sql.org/prepared.html